# Multicols environment not working properly in exercise environment

Tags: multicol, exercises

I am having a problem in using `multicols` environment in exercise environment. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}  
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries\sffamily vv}
\settasks{after-item-skip=3pt,%gap for next row
        before-skip=2pt,%gap from the text above    
          after-skip=0pt,%gap for next question
          label-width=20pt,%width from left
          item-indent=25pt,%indent from left
          label=$\EgyptianBlue\bm{(\alph*)}$,
          column-sep=0em, label-align=left}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}




\begin{document}

\setcounter{Exercise}{0}

\begin{Exercise}



\Question
\Question
\Question










\end{Exercise}
    
\begin{Answer}



\Question $(a)$

\begin{multicols}{4}
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\end{multicols}


\end{Answer}
\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

There is no problem in the code if I start `Answer` environment with a `\Question`, however, if I start with `\multicols` environment (without any `\Question` before `\multicols`), then I get the following error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endmulticols ...le@items \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \balance@columns \return@n...
l.60 \end{multicols}
```

I need to start `Answer` environment with `\multicols`. I also want the answers to be typed from left to right like

```
   1.     2.      3.       4.
   5.     6.      7.       8.
```

Please help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using exam class?  All of your code uses the exercise package instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is discussed in section "4 Known problems" of the `exercise` documentation. You can avoid the error by adding `\EndCurrentQuestion` before the `multicols` environment ends:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}  
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries\sffamily vv}
\settasks{after-item-skip=3pt,%gap for next row
        before-skip=2pt,%gap from the text above    
          after-skip=0pt,%gap for next question
          label-width=20pt,%width from left
          item-indent=25pt,%indent from left
          label=$\EgyptianBlue\bm{(\alph*)}$,
          column-sep=0em, label-align=left}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}




\begin{document}

\setcounter{Exercise}{0}

\begin{Exercise}



\Question
\Question
\Question










\end{Exercise}
    
\begin{Answer}


\begin{multicols}{4}
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\Question $(a)$
\EndCurrentQuestion
\end{multicols}


\end{Answer}
\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Samcarter. Your solution works but now I am having different problem. I need to add the command \EndCurrentQuestion in every set of four answers. Also, the answer number again starts with 1.

Comment: If I use a single \multicols environment, then the answers are typed vertically, but I need them to be horizontal.

Comment: @Deepak If you have a new question, please ask a new question.